# how to use a makefile for mingw on win32

Tags: c, mingw32

i seem to have forgotten what is typed on the command line when using a makefile for a c program on a win32 machine. what i remember is that i should type something like

> mingw32 -make

. but that is not working atm. ive done all the necessary stuff like setting environment mingw variables. any help on the command?

Comment: Make. Mmm… http://xkcd.com/149/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A lot depends on the details of your installation, but I suspect the problem is the space between `mingw32` and `-make`.

You want to use the `mingw32-make` command, not the `mingw32` command with a `-make` argument.