# Getting started with C++ and Spotify API

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, sublimetext2, spotify

I decided to start learning C++ by actually working a little bit with Spotifi's API.

So I downloaded the proper files for the windows environment, and set MinGW to use it to compile.

Now, everything set, I load the Spotify-examples folder in a Sublime2 Project and run a Build, but the problem is that I can't seem to pass the following error:

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:D:\W0RK\Software\spotify-examples\Makefile: file format not recognized; treating as linker script
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe:D:\W0RK\Software\spotify-examples\Makefile:1: syntax error
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
[Finished in 0.4s with exit code 1]
```

This is my custom sublime build config:

```
{
    "cmd": ["C:\\MinGW\\bin\\mingw32-g++.exe", "-Wall", "-time", "--verbose", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name"]
}
```

Am I missing any step in building process?

Comment: This is what I actually had to do as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5214820/how-to-use-a-makefile-for-mingw-on-win32

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to link the Makefile, which will fail since it's not an object file. You need to exclude it from your build process.

Comment: I opened the make file in the editor and executed build, isn't that what are you saying?

Comment: Something in your setup is making the linker try to link the Makefile, which is wrong. It looks like you're telling g++ to actually compile the Makefile itself, which won't work - the Makefile tells a utility called `make` what to give to the compiler - you can't actually build a Makefile.

Comment: Don't know if your familiar with spotify's C++ API examples folder structer, but I've paste it here: http://pastebin.com/VWWK0yQR I understand that I can't acually build a Makefile, but I can't seem to figure another way of trying to build the project, besides opening the Makefile and trying to build, as if I try in the folder root, I get `No such file or directory`

Comment: Please forgive my lack of knowledge, I'm trying to achieve it